# How to split the digits to count the no of times it comes in perl

Tags: perl

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = ('0'..'9');
print "Enter the inp No's : ";
while (($inp = <STDIN>) cmp "\n"){

}
```

angus > perl no.pl
Enter the inp No's : 12123213123

I'm trying to find how many times each no comes and the total of all the digits.How to split each digit and find its occurence

Answer (score 3):

You have not declared $inp. Also, your usage of `cmp` is weird, simple `ne` would work the same and would not confuse anyone.

You can split a string into characters by using an empty pattern in `split` and then count the numbers of occurrences in a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print "Enter the inp No's : ";
while ((my $inp = <STDIN>) ne "\n"){
    my %digits;
    $digits{$_}++ for split //, $inp;
    for (0 .. 9) {
        print "$_ ", $digits{$_} || 0, "\n";
    }
}
```

The canonical way, though, is to use the `tr` operator. As it does not interpolate, we must use eval to get the variable value inside:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

print "Enter the inp No's : ";
my %digits;
while ((my $inp = <STDIN>) ne "\n"){
    for (0 .. 9) {
        my $n = eval "\$inp =~ tr/$_//";
        print "$_ $n\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great. Can you please explain what this line does "$digits{$_}++ for split //, $inp;"

Comment: @Angus: `split //` returns a list of characters. `for` iterates over the list, `++` increments, so for each character, the %digits value corresponding to it is incremented.